# Reverse the display name with split name on SharePoint Spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

I am trying to show displayname from AAD using in my spfx but for the full name i cannot get the array of first item. I know i am missing something from below but couldn't analyse what's missing.

Example:
Name: Fernando, John Maurice,
First Name: John Maurice,
Last Name: Fernando

From below code output what i get is "Maurice John Fernando", But what i want is "John Maurice Fernando"

```
 const nameparts = this.props.context.pageContext.user.displayName.split(/,|\s/).reverse().join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really a SharePoint related question, but more of a Javascript/Regex question. But I'll try to help you out:

What you're doing and why this doesn't work out correctly:
In your scenario, `displayName = 'Fernando, John Maurice'`.
The first thing you do is split this using regular expression `/,|\s/`.
This splits the string on each occurence of a `,` or (`|`) a space `\s`.

The result of this split is an array with 4 elements: `['Fernando', '', 'John', 'Maurice']` (as you can see, all spaces and comma's are no longer present). When you `reverse()` this, the resulting array is `['Maurice', 'John', '', 'Fernando']`. And `join()`ing these elements to a new string with spaces results in `'Maurice John  Fernando'`

So the solution would be to not split the initial string on spaces, but only on the comma. The regex will be just this: `/,/`. Now the array will be just two elements after the `split()`: `['Fernando', ' John Maurice']` (notice the space before John is still here because we just split on the `,` and not the space). Reversing this array will result in array `[' John Maurice', 'Fernando']`. This can be joined just the way you did, resulting in the desired string `' John Maurice Fernando'`. For completeness you could add a `.trim()` to remove redundant spaces.

TL/DR

```js
const nameparts = this.props.context.pageContext.user.displayName.split(/,/).reverse().join(" ").trim();
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, it works Perfect !

Comment: Great to hear! Could you mark my answer as the answer to your question? Thanks!